# AJAX is not submitting data to database

Tags: ajax, database, wpdb

I have a quiz application which stores user scores to a variable. There is a blueprint object for every user that looks like this:

```
function User (theName, theEmail) {
  this.name = theName;
  this.email = theEmail;
  this.quizScores = [];
  this.currentScore = 0;
}
```

New user created like this:

```
var user1 = new User (lastItem.name);
```

Then there is event listener for button click, which increments user score. Inside the same event listener function I make AJAX request to store user score to database:

```
 dbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

        question1.currentQuestion++;
        if(question1.currentQuestio

n > 3 ) {
      container.style = "display: none;"
      var finished = document.createElement("h2");
      finished.setAttribute("name", "score");
      finished.innerHTML = "You scored: " + user1.currentScore;
      body.appendChild(finished);

      jQuery.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: window.location,
          data: { score: user1.currentScore }
      }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("data sent");
      });
    }
```

I get consoled `data sent` but database shows no values stored.

Then inside functions.php I just check globally (not inside the function) if `$_POST['score]` is empty or not, if empty, echo a notice, otherwise insert into database.

```
if( empty( $_POST['score'] ) ) { echo "score is null!"; die(); }
if(isset($_POST['score']))
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'username';
    $dataa = array(
            'score' => $_POST['score']
    );
    $score = $wpdb->insert($table, $dataa);
    die();
```

The problem is that values doesn't get stored, but neither do I get a message `score is null!` on the screen. It looks like there is no connection between my script.js file with AJAX request and functions.php code above. I'm not sure if `URL` in AJAX request is correct and I pass the data to `$_POST[]` correctly.

What I'm doing here wrong? I have managed to get data from DB to JS using ajax already, but I can't make it work when posting from JS to DB.

EDIT: I changed AJAX `.done` function to `console.log(data)` instead of success message and it consoles out the whole html template for some reason? 
Some people suggested me to change AJAX url from `window.location` to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?` but that returns

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST http://example.design/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php? 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I would validate the POST score before trying to insert it into the database, that way you can do something like `if( empty( $_POST['score'] ) ) { echo "score is null!"; die(); }` which is super helpful for debugging. Also, your code examples are incomplete, please edit your question to complete them. Also can you verify that `user1.currentScore` actually has a value? Have you considered using the less error prone and easier to debug REST API instead of the ancient admin ajax endpoints?

Comment: But as I know $_POST takes name attributes and I’m passing a variable to it, maybe that’s the problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Can you pass anything to $_POST[]? Coz when working with forms, if I pas to it anything else than name attribute of the input field, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you can, also your check uses `isset` but what if it is set, but it's set to "null"? Have you actually checked that `user1.currentScore` is defined, and has a valid value? Again, please edit your question to include the necessary code, not the cut down version. There's an edit link at the bottom of the question just underneath the tags in gray you can use to update your question, there is not enough information at the moment to answer it

Comment: Okay, i think I'm really close so I will just ask this. Do I set my url inside ajax request to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`? If I continue to have problem, I will edit my question

Comment: I don't know enough about how your code is set up to answer. I wasn't kidding when I said your question can't be answered without more information, I literally only have what you put in your question to go by

Comment: @TomJNowell Edited with more details.

Comment: The 404 on admin-ajax is unexpected, and not normal WP behaviour. The worst case scenario for admin ajax if anything goes wrong is "0", at least the REST API will tell you if you forget something. Can you expand your PHP code? It's not clear if it's in a function, a class, or just dangling in the root of functions.php